# mpirun is causing data leaks in my python process manager. I have bricked 2 supercomputer nodes

Tags: subprocess, mpi

This is my first post on here, so bear with me.

I am running Quantum Espresso (`pw.x` in this case) on my university cluster on only 1 node in this case, with setup conditions given at the bottom. I am using python as a process manager to change files, extract data, etc. within this,

```
types=["GaAs","InAs","GaSb","InSb"]
calcs=["scf","nscf","bands","pp"]
bandgaps=[]
for typ in types:
    for calc in calcs:
        shutil.copy("{0}/{1}.U.{2}.in".format(curdir,typ,calc),\
                    "{0}/{1}.int.{2}.in".format(intdir,typ,calc))
        filein1="{0}/{1}.int.{2}.in".format(intdir,typ,calc)
        command=['mpirun -n {2} pw.x < {0}.int.{1}.in &> {0}.int.{1}.out'.format(typ,calc,num_procs)]
        subprocess.run(command,cwd=intdir,shell=True)
    bandgaps.append(QE_extract_bandgap("{0}/{1}.int.nscf.out".format(intdir,typ)))
#This has been slightly edited for clarity, as most of the earlier script was just putting in other parameters into the input scripts.
```

where `num_procs` is the number of processors, `typ` is the type of material I am running the calculation for, and `calc` is the type of calculation (scf, nscf, bands).
This all runs reasonably well within its loop of running calculations with different parameters. Then quantum espresso will have an issue on the one step, and not complete a job because of this error

```
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     Error in routine mix_rho (1):
     negative dr2
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

     stopping ...
```

This is a normal error I can deal with, though I have to manually weak some parameters. The other calculations based upon the scf calculation, so the nscf and the bands calculations, will run.

Afterwards, on the next `typ`,  until I get this error in the output files (there are 40 lines of the `Bus error` line, one for each processor):

```
[tcad37.iue.tuwien.ac.at:mpi_rank_18][error_sighandler] Caught error: Bus error (signal 7)
[tcad37.iue.tuwien.ac.at:mpi_rank_19][error_sighandler] Caught error: Bus error (signal 7)
[tcad37.iue.tuwien.ac.at:mpi_rank_27][error_sighandler] Caught error: Bus error (signal 7)
[tcad37.iue.tuwien.ac.at:mpi_rank_34][error_sighandler] Caught error: Bus error (signal 7)
[tcad37.iue.tuwien.ac.at:mpi_rank_36][error_sighandler] Caught error: Bus error (signal 7)
[tcad37.iue.tuwien.ac.at:mpi_rank_0][error_sighandler] Caught error: Bus error (signal 7)

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 180018 RUNNING AT tcad37
=   EXIT CODE: 7
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Bus error (signal 7)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

The program has to abort from the cluster, and afterwards, whichever node this was run on is essentially dead, with any job being sent to it being told that there is no memory available to run said job.

My slurm shebang for the record:

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH -J 3Uopt
#SBATCH --output=opt3.txt
#SBATCH -n 40
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=40
#SBATCH --time 3-00:00:00   # max runtime hh:mm:ss`
```

I believe that the problem is that the `mpirun` process doesn't close its shell properly when it receives an error. That is, I think, what the Bus error means, that the shell that I had previously opened has all of the space taken on the cluster (this node has 40 processors on it), but it hasn't properly registered for some reason. I do't know how to fix this, though I suspect it is a problem with subprocess.run and mpirun not closeing a crashed shell.

Any advice would be welcome. There is limited debugging I can do at the moment, as if I do some and it failed, I brick another node.

Comment: Try running `pidof pw.x` before `mpirun` and make sure there is no remaining process. your script tries to run 16 MPI jobs, how many success and how many attempts? If you suspect `python` is somehow involved, simply write a shell script and see how it goes.

Comment: Thank you, M. Gouiaillardet. Once the nodes have cleared up, I will do this. I might also start a much slower process on only 2 cores, wait for it to crash, and then see what processes are running. Thanks.